# Rails jQuery mobile relation caching views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4 jQuery mobile app, if I use in the controller:

```
@sales = @bill.sales
```

In a `@bill` show view I have `@bill` details and then a list of `@sales`. If I then add a sale but return a different view, other than bill show, it shows the sales correctly with the new sale. If I then go back to a list of bills and select a bill show, the sales are cached without the new addition.

The reason I don't redirect to show after adding a new sale is that a sale may be added by an admin, a cashier or a waitress, all of whom have different permissions and a different controller. Only the admin uses the Bills controller.

If I use

```
  @sales = Sale.where(:bill_id => @bill.id)
```

it always shows the correctly updated list and does not cache the last view of sales.

Here is my view code

```
<ul  data-role="listview" data-theme="e">

<li>Bill Number: <%= @bill.bill_number %></li>

  -- more bill stuff ...

</ul>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<% unless @sales.empty? -%>

  <ul  data-role="listview" data-theme="a">

  <% @sales.each do |sale| %>

     <li><%= sale.quantity %>&nbsp;<%= sale.item %>&nbsp;<%= sale.commission_staff %>&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(sale.amount, :precision => 2) %></li>

  <% end %>

     <li>Total Amount: <%= number_with_precision(@sales_total, :precision => 2) %></li>

  </ul>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: And what is you question? Do you want to know why it is happend?

Comment: Yes. Why is Rails caching the last shown html.erb view? Oddly, it will show a variable with the updated item totals but not the newly added item detail rows.

Comment: Are you caching this yourself? Cache is not something that "magically" happens, you have to explicitly tell what you want to cache.

Comment: No. I ahve not set any caching.

Comment: Please check the database queries that are executed. Rails can cache those as well. It seems like `@bill.sales` does not perform the query, but uses a cached result (which is akward). So probably this is not the case, but please check just to rule it out.

Comment: I already stopped using relations in the controller and forcing a query like @sales = Sale.where(:bill_id => @bill.id). If nothing else works I might even change all controller queries to find_by_sql to prevent caching if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the culprit here is jQuery Mobile and not Rails. jQuery Mobile uses UI trickery to load multiple "screens" and then shift between them when the user clicks through, rather than load each "screen" when it is clicked to.

So it is not Rails imposing some sort of caching, it is your browser that is naturally caching. When you go back to the list of bills, that whole set of screens (list of bills + each bill) is not being refreshed. If you refresh while on the list of bills, then click through to the bill where there is a new sale, is it up to date? If so, jQuery Mobile is causing this.

To fix, you should force a refresh when a new bill is added, or mess with appending new sale info via an Ajax call.

Comment: I tried to add data-cache="never" but it seemed to make no difference.   Then, suddenly the problem went away and it started behaving.

Comment: If I added a timestamp to the page id, would that fool jQM into thinking that each page was unique and never caching it? Or is this the browser just caching the URL? In my case it seems like the problem is jQM, not the browser.

Comment: You shouldn't think of it as caching. I should have avoided the word. jQM is loading your views into the DOM, and then based on user action is manipulating what is shown/hidden. It does this instead of using page loads like a regular web page. The problem you are having is that the new data is not being refreshed, because navigating to it is manipulating what is seen - not what is being loaded. You have to manually refresh or ajax the content in when it is updated.

Comment: Given that the need to update pages in a dynamic site is fundamental, that would mitigate against the use of JQM for anything except static sites. I wish they had an option which just reloaded the whole page and did the fancy touch responses and styling.